# What is causing the soft keyboard to stop responding?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, keyevent

I'm experiencing something I cannot describe entirely.

I somehow keep doing something that messes with the soft keyboard, not just in my application, but on the entire device.

So, I'm developing a game with OpenGl ES 2.0. Everything was fine before I implemented the GLSurfaceView, but after that on random occasions the soft keyboard stopped responding in for instance the native messenger app.

I've seen this happen with previous projects of mine, but also on other phones that are not used as debugging devices after installing OpenGl-based games.

The main problem is I don't understand what is causing this, so I don't know where to start looking.

When the keyboard is not responding, it is logging a warning on tapping a key.

```
02-18 15:08:29.924: W/ViewRootImpl(1261): Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_G, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=93568743, downTime=93568743, deviceId=-1, source=0x101 }
```

It feels like it has something to do with a memory overload, but I can not simulate a situation where it always happens, so I'm not entirely sure.

I would love to provide some code, but as I don't know what is causing this, I don't know what to show.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The focus is "hanged" on the glES view. Next time you stumble across this, force-kill the game and see if it still happens.

Also may be a bug that prevents context-change for input events, but this would manifest only if in some way the gl View got leaked, and the UIService itself is done for.

Comment: Force-killing the game doesn't help the situation, force-killing the messenger-app and launching it again does. After that everything works fine.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct, because it led me to solving the problem. 
It is probably considered a rookie-mistake, but I believe many mobile-developers don't fully understand the garbage-collector, memory-management, etc. (I know I don't).

I passed the activity as a context to the GLRenderer and used it in the GLRenderer to communicate back to the UI-thread, this caused the leaking of the activity/glView.

Solved it by passing getApplicationContext() to the renderer and communicate back to the activity with Handlers.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, or still doing something stupid.